# how to access pcf user services in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, cloud-foundry

I have a web service which connects to db2 and oracle database , currently i am connecting my database by hard coding its db credentials in application.properties file , which is a very bad practice.

And i have created a java class where am creating the datasource bean of those db.
My webservices is hosted on PCF.
So i have added user services on PCF and binded it to my app there .

But now the question is as i want to store db credentials on pcf , how will i set up my connection (access datasource object) in my code application.

please provide me step by step procedure or if there is any project available on github please share the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spring Cloud Connectors](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-connectors.html#_spring_service_connector):

- [DB2 connection configuration](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-cloud-foundry-connector.html#_db2)
- [Oracle connection configuration](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-cloud-foundry-connector.html#_oracle)

Add service binding to your manifest the service binding

```
services:
  - oracle-database-service
  - db2-database-service
```

You need to register the Oracle and databases inside PCF as services and bind application. [PCF documentation](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html).

1. Create oracle service `cf create-user-provided-service oracle-database-service -p '{"uri":"oracle://user:pass@dbhost:1521/db"}'`
2. Bind new service to your existing application `cf bind-service <app name> oracle-database-service`
3. Repeat the similar steps for db2
4. Restart cf `cf restart`

[Similar solution for SAP](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/07/13/connecting-to-a-hana-database-from-pivotal-cloud-foundry/)